# Replacing number-limited tab-navigation in application

Tags: desktop-application, tabs, applications

I've got a small desktop application which features a tab-view to show all plugins which the user can use.

This is the desktop app right now:

[image]

In the next version I will include a plugin API so the users can add their own plugins.

The very limited number of tabs makes it necessary to switch to something more versatile (a control which takes an undefined amount of these plugins.

I thought vertical tabs with an optional button to scroll the list up and down.

Do you have better ideas?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VDOG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with Mac style to display tab menu then the vertical tab works but not very conventional. Typically the horizontal tab bar can support a good number of tabs because of the desktop screen real estate (see airport settings menu below).

[image: OSX with several tabs]

If that's not enough, you should adopt a column list style settings menu but you might have to customize it a bit to fit your setting options.

[image]